# Yii2 UrlManager Rule For String

Tags: yii2, yii2-urlmanager

I'm trying to create a simple rule url, and I can't get it to work.

I want the following rule:

```
mysite.com/[username]
```

to go to

```
mysite.com/kit/page?id=[username]
```

Is this possible?. Right now I only have one rule, but I need to keep that one as well

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    '' => 'site/index',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are saying that you have an existing page `mysite.com/kit/page?id=[username]` which should be shown if you type in the URL `mysite.com/[username]` in the address bar, if yes then you can update the `urlManager` like below

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        '<id:\w+>' => 'kit/page'
    ]
]
```

Ideally, I would use `mysite.com/kit/[username]` to avoid conflicts with any other controller which somehow matches up with any username and use `'kit/<id:\w+>' => 'kit/page'`.

**Note : `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), so if your username can have any other character allowed you might have to update the [pattern](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlrule#$pattern-detail), for example to allow `-` you should change the rule to `'<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'kit/page'`**